# a trouble of copying array in C++

Tags: c++

I am copying an array in C++, here is the code:

```
int arr1[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
int *source = arr1;
size_t sz = sizeof(arr1) / sizeof(*arr1); // number of elements
int *dest = new int[sz];                // uninitialized elements
while (source != arr1 + sz)
    *dest++ = *source++; //  copy element and increment pointers

int *p = dest;
while (p != dest + sz) {
    cout << *p++ << endl;
}
```

after running the code above-mentioned, I got:

```
714124054
51734
9647968
9639960
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

what's the trouble?

Comment: int *p = dest;
now the p point the end of the array!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The array is copied properly, though, by incrementing `dest` you are losing the actual beginning.

You need to keep a copy of `dest` to loop after it. Also don't forget to free the memory after you have allocated it.

Finally, in C++ you'll probably want to use `std::vector` instead of arrays that does all this in a transparent way while trading a minimum amount of performance.

```
int arr1[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
int *source = arr1;
size_t sz = sizeof(arr1) / sizeof(*arr1); // number of elements
int *dest = new int[sz];                // uninitialized elements
int *d = dest;
while (source != arr1 + sz)
    *d++ = *source++; //  copy element and increment pointers

int *p = dest;
while (p != dest + sz) {
    cout << *p++ << endl;
}

[...]
delete[] dest;
```

Answer (score 0):

The starting pointer is not saved with `int *dest = new int[sz];`, after `*dest++` in the while loop, so the output is out of range of the array.

The revised code:

```
int arr1[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
int *source = arr1;
size_t sz = sizeof(arr1) / sizeof(*arr1); // number of elements
int *dest = new int[sz];                // uninitialized elements
int *temp_dest = dest;
while (source != arr1 + sz)
    *temp_dest++ = *source++; //  copy element and increment pointers

int *p = dest;
while (p != dest + sz) {
    cout << *p++ << endl;
}
```